# Update on TableController in Azure Mobile Services fails

Tags: azure-mobile-services

When I do a Patch (updateasync) on a tablecontroller I get the following error:

```
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Message='The client is attempting to use optimistic concurrency in
connection with updates and inserts but the current 'SimpleMappedEntityDomainManager`2' 
implementation does not set the original version required to support this. Please implement the 
method 'SetOriginalVersion' and provide the original value.', 
Id=00000000-0000-0000-5d00-0080000000ff, Category='App.Controllers.Tables'
```

I am using the MappedEntityDomainManager as I have a pre-existing DB that I have hooked up.

Lookup and Insert all work fine.

Comment: Can you post the code for your model and your DTO (the types which are being mapped between each other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your `SimpleMappedEntityDomainManager<TDTO, TModel>` implementation with the following method:

```
protected override void SetOriginalVersion(TModel model, byte[] version)
{
    this.context.Entry(model).OriginalValues["Version"] = version;
}
```

Where `"Version"` is the name of the property in your model class which stores the version of the item (usually of type `timestamp`)

If you do not have any property in your database that stores the version (mapped to the `Version` or `__version` property in the outgoing DTO), then you can have an empty override:

```
protected override void SetOriginalVersion(TModel model, byte[] version)
{
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation for this feature, so I'll forward this issue to the product team to have it corrected.